# wx.Timer for animation

Tags: python, wxpython

Simple animation, this works but would the replaced image data stay in the buffer?
And is using timer for animation harmful to CPU? I mean like `self.timer.Start(25)` does some cool animations from individual image files.

```
self.nm = ['01.png', '02.png', '03.png', '04.png']
self.stop = 0

def time(self, event):
    self.count += 1
    if self.count == 1:
        self.anime = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, wx.Bitmap(self.nm[self.stop], wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))
    if self.count == 2:
        self.anime.Show(0)
        if self.stop == 3:
            self.timer.Stop()
        else:
            self.stop+=1
            self.count = 0
    event.Skip()
```

Comment: ... Wait... you're not *really* loading each image each time it needs to be shown... right?

Comment: i guess i am... is it bad?  o.O

Comment: Why not just hold the wx.StaticBitmaps in self.nm instead of holding only the file names and loading every time?

Answer (score 1):

First, you're indeed reloading each image every time it needs to be shown. Yes, this is very bad, because that is a lot of disk I/O, and the disk is probably the slowest device your program has to interact with. Avoid using the disk at all costs when you can.

Now, to alleviate this, a few options:

- Create your own subclass of [`wx.animate.Animation`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.animate.Animation-class.html) to match your animation (need to override some methods from `wx.animate.Animation` but also some from [`wx.animate.AnimationBase`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.animate.AnimationBase-class.html). This is the proper solution to this problem, but isn't the simplest.
- Use [`wx.animate.AnimationCtrl`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.animate.AnimationCtrl-class.html) if your animation can be converted to a .gif without acceptable loss of detail. This is slightly easier than the previous solution, since you don't have to write any animation code.
- Keep the bitmaps in memory; simply store them in a list somewhere ("somewhere" does not mean inside the `time` function itself, as that would still get reloaded every time the function `time` is called; "somewhere" means as a member of the object that the `time` function is a part of).
- Keep all bitmaps in the UI, and simply toggle visibility between them when you need to change frame.

Comment: thanks.. what if images are loaded, then their position changed on time? may be timer.Start(100)

Comment: Yes, use a `wx.Timer` if you're going for one of the last two approaches.